# Is "boundary condition testing" on UI (TextBox's max length) a good idea?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I know that boundary condition testing is a good thing to do in software testing. But in my opinion, I think testing textbox's max length with boundary condition testing is not a good idea.

For example, I have a textbox which set the limit to 10 characters. Is it necessary to test with all below tests?

1. Input a 5 char text and expect that it would pass.
2. Input a 10 char text and expect the test would pass.
3. Input an 11 char text and expect that they cannot do that.

*I tried to search about applying boundary condition testing on UI but I found very little information on it.*

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a technique called [Equivalence Class Partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning). Let's take your example. There are a few different EC's you could use to evaluate the limit on a text field. Here's a table:

> ```
>     +------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
>     | Factor:    | Factor:          | Risk:             | Risk:             |
>     | Size       | Characters       | Downstream        | Upstream          |
>     |            |                  |                   |                   |
>     +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
>     | 0          | A-Z              | Are there any     | Ditto.            |
>     | 1          | a-z              | things that are   | Is there anything |
>     | >1         | Any UTF-8        | affected down-    | affected by your  |
>     | 10         | Any UTF-16       | stream? Does      | input after the   |
>     | >10        | etc.             | any of the other  | fact? For instance|
>     |            |                  | conditions cause  | a login form might|
>     |            |                  | problems for      | have a "Name"     |
>     |            |                  | other functions?  | with a length of  |
>     |            |                  |                   | 9 somewhere else  |
>     |            |                  |                   | in the application|
>     |            |                  |                   |                   |
>     +------------+------------------+-------------------+-------------------
> ```

Based on this table, you can try variations of the input (from more than just BVA) and see what makes sense. Look at the risks and see if anything you did had an effect upstream or downstream in the application.

Now, if you get to a point where the combinations are too many, use another technique called [All-pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) testing. This will limit the combinations you have.

At the end of the day, its not about exhaustive testing, its about making sure the risks are properly explored and tested appropriately.

Here's a little **[3 minute video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P1Hv2sUPKeM) which is also a good resource and elaborates on the fact that BVA and EC go hand-in-hand.**

To answer your specific question:

> *Is “boundary condition testing” on UI (TextBox's max length) a good idea? Is it necessary to test with all below tests?*

Yes. Those are some pretty basic boundaries, although you're missing 2 cases IMO:

- Null case: does it matter if the field is null?
- 0 case: is 0 significant? Zero can mean the numeric "0", or it could mean passing in characters that aren't really there from an end-user perspective; for instance, using spaces. Zero is different than null, since you can pass in spaces, etc into a field too. Maybe you can pass in 11 spaces and your application is happy? I don't know, but it is a boundary worth exploring.

Based on what your application does, you'll need to evaluate other risk factors and come up with tests associated with those risks.